# How to convert BigQuery SPLIT() function output into columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How can i take the output of the SPLIT() function, an array of size 2, meaning it contains 2 elements and convert the two elements into two columns respectively.

Input:

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

Comment: No it does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below way -

```
SELECT SPLIT(columnname, spliter)[OFFSET(0)] id,
       SPLIT(columnname, spliter)[OFFSET(1)] point
from tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array references:

```
select split_output[ordinal(1)] as offset,
       split_output[ordinal(2)] as point
```

Comment: the suggested syntax is not supported in BigQuery.

Comment: @ronencozen . . . I'm not sure what you mean.  This is based on the columns in your question.

Comment: I meant that there is no such function as split_output in BigQuery.

Comment: @ronencozen . . . If you look at the question, you will see that the sample data has `split_output` as a column header.  As the author of the question, I'm surprised I need to point this out.

Comment: Gordon, you are right it is indeed the column name, nevertheless the suggested syntax is not supported,  ordinal(1)  is probably an equivalent to BigQuery offset[0], and the call to the split function is missing from the proposed query.